# Recent order should include the addition of a comment and the change in accepted or closed status

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-accounts, statistics

In the Users page, Stats tab, the Answers section sorted by Recent, it should bump up answers that have comments added or have had their accepted answer or closed status changed.

It would also be nice if, at least when ordered by Recent, the answers include a datestamp similar to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would also bump those questions on the homepage, which is not desirable -- would be near-catastrophic in fact.

We'd be optimizing for controversy (stuff that has lots of comments) and bikeshed discussions.

Comment: Fair enough, while the two concepts are implemented using the one feature anyway.